# What are the equivalents of intents in Windowsphone 8 application development?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I thought of an app to upload photos when they are taken. How do I notify my app when a photo has been taken in wp8 programmatically? Are there anything similar to intents in android? In android, I would listen for an intent when a photo has been taken and get that photo. In my windows phone 8 application. how do I get the system to notify my application when the photo has been taken and process it?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but don't think it's possible in WP8.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek not exactly the equivalent of the Android intent but there is an API for auto-upload photo apps in WP8 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571205%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific API since Windows Phone 8 that allows auto-uploading photos for third-party apps: [Auto-upload apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571205%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (MSDN)

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for since the agent will only launch under certain conditions and not immediately when a new photo is taken. For example, Wi-Fi and an external power source are required, in order to reduce the battery drain.

However that's the only viable solution for auto-uploading photos in a background task.

Comment: I am marking this as right answer as windowsph8 system has not matured enough and this seems to be the only viable option. I was wondering why there was no dropbox. I have my answer